# how to make a camera in tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, coordinate-transformation

I have a grid based coordinate system where the distance between each grid center is a set number of pixels. Doing this in OpenGL I made a camera using view/projection matrices. Changing view center and scale for the whole scene could be made by setting matrix elements.

This is from a prototype using OpenGL that I made before going full Tcl/Tk. The node positions are {[1..5], [1..3]} (text at fractional y-offset):

[image]

How would I accomplish this in Tcl/Tk? I'm reading about [canvas zooming](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4844) however was hoping for a smaller example; create line between 1..2, 3..4, pan, zoom, pan again, zoom again.

Answer (score 1):

The Tk canvas widget supports panning (it's following the Tk scrollable window protocol) but doesn't allow zooming of the viewport. (It has a [`scale` method](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M79), but that just changes the coordinates of the objects, which is not the same thing; in particular, it doesn't change things like font sizes, embedded window/image sizes, line thicknesses, etc.) You can control the panning via the `xview` and `yview` methods, as with any scrollable Tk widget.

However, there's an alternative that might be more suitable for you.

Paul Obermeier's [Tcl3D](http://www.tcl3d.org/), which allows you to use OpenGL together with Tcl/Tk, would let you keep a lot of what you've done so far with writing OpenGL code, and yet it still provides the benefits of being able to use Tcl/Tk. Basically, the core of it is that it includes [Togl](http://www.tcl3d.org/html/docModules.html#Togl), a package for presenting an OpenGL drawing surface as a Tk widget, together with bindings to the OpenGL API. I know of quite a few people who use Tcl3D to power their (both commercial and open-source) applications, and you'd end up with a hybrid that should provide the best of both worlds. (Also, it's considered entirely reasonable to include some custom C code in a Tcl application that needs a bit more performance in a critical spot; it's outright *good style* to do this. Complex GUIs sometimes need that sort of thing.)

Comment: it is good you mention Tcl3D and Togl because I had the (false) impression they were poorly maintained. alas, the prototype did garbage opengl using legacy pipeline (the prototype served mainly other purposes) so nothing worth reusing. Key here is applying a transform on draw, which after a little reading `scale` does not seem to do. Q: does Tcl3D and Togl include picking features? I open context menues with content specialized for the node type (node color in the pic indicates type of sorts) and standard Tk seem to have good support for it.

Comment: Q: do you know of a better forum for discussion on the subject?